# Can older ASP.net core applications (like asp.net core 2.0) run on a server with asp.net core 2.2 runtime installed on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I have some older asp.net core 2.0 programs that are running on a server with a asp.net 2.0 server bundler installed on it. I have recently starting working with asp.net 2.1 and 2.2 and I know that those won't run correctly if I don't have the updated server bundler from Microsoft installed. Will my older programs stop working if I install the new bundlers or will everything continue to work as it does now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple runtime of .Net core running side by side on your server. Here is some documention from Microsoft:

> To install applications with dependencies on different versions of .NET, we recommend .NET Core. .NET Core offers side-by-side installation of different versions of the .NET Core runtime on the same machine. This side-by-side installation allows multiple services on the same server, each of them on its own version of .NET Core. It also lowers risks and saves money in application upgrades and IT operations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

Comment: I appreciate it. For the life of me I couldn't find this documentation when I searched for it.